# How to add multiple *.sitemap files to mvcsitemapprovider during session start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I want to associate multiple sitemaps to mvcsitemapprovider during session_start event as sitemaps names and locations are retrieved based upon the type of client/user. But, according to documents related to mvcsitemapprovider, all *.sitemaps are getting associated to mvcsitemapprovider during application start. Is there any way, I can provide this functionality using this control?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in per session functionality, but you could [implement your own ICacheProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152115/make-mvc-sitemap-unique-per-session-not-user) to handle this requirement. Also see [MvcSiteMapProvider 4.0 - Extending the Cache](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/13/mvcsitemapprovider-4-extending-the-cache) and [Multiple SiteMaps in One Application](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Sitemaps-in-One-Application) for more guidance.

Do note that the primary reason this doesn't exist out of the box is because it would be extremely memory intensive and would not scale to very many users. Unless your navigation is completely different per user, I wouldn't recommend using this approach. A better alternative is to use the [preservedRouteParameters approach](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match) to force some route values to match any value (in your case userid or clientid), and then use [ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider), [SiteMapTitleAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Action-Filter-Attributes#sitemaptitle), and/or manual updating of SiteMapNode properties per request to control the visibility of the node.

Please see my open question here and explain to me why you would want to do this on GitHub, as it renders most of the features useless: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/16#issuecomment-22229604